# Parse error: com.parse.AggregateException: There were multiple errors

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm getting a strange exception when initializing Parse. Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.parse.AggregateException: There were multiple errors.
1 at com.parse.Parse.waitForTask (Parse.java:828)
2 at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser (ParseUser.java:877)
3 at com.parse.Parse.initialize (Parse.java:137)
4 at com.tobuy.android.TobuyApplication.setupParse (TobuyApplication.java:259)
5 at com.tobuy.android.TobuyApplication.onCreate (TobuyApplication.java:205)
```

The code on TobuyApplication:259 is simply Parse initialization:

```
Parse.initialize(this, Configuration.PARSE_APP_ID, Configuration.PARSE_CLIENT_ID);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What do the docs say about what the parameters to initialize are supposed to be?

Comment: [docs](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new) are pretty straightforward, the same thing I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized `Parse` on the `Application` class properly? like instructed on the quick start guide?

If you have followed the quickstart guide, you can try getting more info by putting the code on a `try-catch block`. Such as :

```
try {
    Parse.initialize(this, Configuration.PARSE_APP_ID, Configuration.PARSE_CLIENT_ID);
} catch (ParseException exception) {
    //do something with the exception
}
```

Also, you can try debugging the app, put the breakpoint on the erroneous line and step forward once at a time to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @reidzeible, but ParseException is not thrown by the corresponding block. I will try updating the Parse jar (I'm using 1.5 and 1.9.2 is the latest)